# Interfaces In PLSQL

Tags: object, plsql, interface

Is it possible to use interfaces with objects in plsql?

For example say I have a bunch of objects and want to sort them by date with a generic function. Could I have something like the following?

```
create or replace interface DateInterface
(
    member function get_date return date
)
/
create or replace type TypeA implements DateInterface
(
    my_date date,
    member function get_date return date
)
/
create or replace type body TypeA is
    member function get_date return date is
    begin
        return my_date;
    end;
end;
/
create or replace type dateTable as table of DateInterface;
/
function EarliestDate (dates dateTable) returns date is
    l_earliestDate date;
begin
    l_earliestDate := dates(1);
    for i in dates.first .. dates.last
    loop
        if l_earliestDate.get_date > dates(i).get_date then
            l_earliestDate := dates(i);
        end if;
    end loop;
    return l_earliestDate;
end;
```

I know I could have them inherit a class, but is there anything for doing this with an interface which would be more flexible?

Comment: Please describe in more details what you mean by _"interface"_. If you are thinking something like [Java interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29) then the answer is no - PL/SQL doesn't have that kind of interfaces. If you just want to compare object types look object comparison member methods, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32779141/272735

Comment: PL/SQL doesn't have this syntax, but I wish it did. For example, the [Oracle Data Cartridge Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/addci/using-user-defined-aggregate-functions.html) for user-defined aggregate functions requires a type with methods `ODCIAggregateInitialize`, `ODCIAggregateIterate`, `ODCIAggregateMerge` and `ODCIAggregateTerminate`. If we could specify something like `implements ODCIAggregate`, the compiler could check that it really did and provide some clear errors if not. Polymorphic table functions could be another use.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle supports interfacing external sources like Java and C languages within its procedures and functions using the LANGUAGE clause in them. Implement the date sorting logic of the objects in a procedure or a function and interface with other programming languages.

For reference, see [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chthree.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but Oracle has sort of OO support now in PLSQL:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adobj/inheritance-in-sql-object-types.html#GUID-A5FE7A3B-7C1C-430A-8095-76AE955119C9

You have inheritance etc. with that. So you could do sort of an interface for PLSQL Object Type Objects
But it comes with problems. Eg. storing in tables.
See https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/object-types